# working with facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I was reading about FB Graph API in this page. Please see the section **Authorization**

They say that

> At a high level, you need to get an
>   access token for the Facebook user.

I am confused. How do i get the logeed in users access token in my website

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get a logged in user's access token. Once a user is authenticated, you receive an access token to be able to see/manipulate that user's data, depending on what permissions you have requested from that user.

This is well documented in the "Authentication" section of the developer documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/